# Change date format of moment(obj.created_at).toDate()

Tags: javascript, angular, date, momentjs

I need to change format from **2022-12-30** to **30-12-2022** (DD/MM/YYYY)

But I need to keep it as **DATE** object, **not as string**

Here what I've tried:

```
obj.created_at                                        // return string 2022-12-30 (YYYY-MM-DD)
new Date(obj.created_at)                              // return date 12/30/2022 (MM/DD/YYYY)
new Date(obj.created_at).toLocaleDateString('id-ID')  // return string 30/12/2022 (DD/MM/YYYY), this is the correct format, but it's a string not a date
moment(obj.created_at).toDate()                       // return date 12/30/2022 (MM/DD/YYYY)
moment(obj.created_at).format('DD/MM/YYYY')           // return string 30/12/2022 (DD/MM/YYYY), this is the correct format, but it's a string not a date
moment(obj.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate()         // return date 12/30/2022 (MM/DD/YYYY)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You can't, a date object does not have a format! It just represents a moment in time. If you display it as a string only then can you format it.

Comment: As phuzi said already, you cannot do what you described. What you can do instead, is to keep your date object around as `Date` and only format it when you need to display it, or send it to a server, or whatever. That's what everybody else does.

Comment: ouw okay, nice information, thanks for your response btw phuzi & octavian :)